# Convert image into ASCII art

Tags: python, image, ascii-art

I made a python script that takes an image and converts it into an ASCII-art representation and saves it as a .txt file.
The logic is somewhat simple. It resizes the image to a manageable size, converts it to gray-scale, takes the value of each pixel and assigns it a character according to it. Then appends the characters to a string and wrap it to the number of pixels of width.
Can this be improved in any way? Does it follows conventions and best practices?

```
import PIL.Image
image=None
def closest(myList, myNumber):
    from bisect import bisect_left
    pos=bisect_left(myList, myNumber)
    if pos==0:
        return myList[0]
    if pos==len(myList):
        return myList[-1]
    before=myList[pos-1]
    after=myList[pos]
    if after-myNumber<myNumber-before:
        return after
    else:
        return before
def resize(image,new_width=300):
    width,height=image.size
    new_height=int((new_width*height/width)/2.5)
    return image.resize((int(round(new_width)), int(round(new_height))))
def to_greyscale(image):
    return image.convert("L")
def pixel_to_ascii(image):
    pixels=image.getdata()
    a=list("@$B%8&WM#*oahkbdpqwmZO0QLCJUYXzcvunxrjft/\|()1{}[]?-_+~<>i!lI;:,\"^`'. "[::-1]) #remove the slice to get light mode
    pixlist=list(pixels)
    minp=min(pixlist)
    maxp=max(pixlist)
    vals=[]
    lst=list(range(minp,maxp+1))
    def chunks(lst,n):
        import numpy as np
        return np.array_split(lst,n)
    lchunks=list(chunks(lst,len(a)))
    for chunk in lchunks:
        vals.append(chunk[0])
    avals={vals[i]:a[i] for i in range(len(vals))}
    ascii_str="";    
    for pixel in pixels:
        ascii_str+=avals[closest(vals,pixel)];
    return ascii_str
if __name__='main'
    path=#drop your path here
    image=PIL.Image.open(path)
    name=input("enter the image name here: ")
    image=resize(image);
    greyscale_image=to_greyscale(image)
    ascii_str=pixel_to_ascii(greyscale_image)
    img_width=greyscale_image.width
    ascii_str_len=len(ascii_str)
    ascii_img=""
    for i in range(0,ascii_str_len, img_width):
        ascii_img+=ascii_str[i:i+img_width]+"\n"
    with open("{}.txt".format(n    ame), "w") as f:
        f.write(ascii_img);
    print(ascii_img)
```

Comment: Dumping your code through [Black](https://black.vercel.app/) will give instant benefits! (as well as find a few syntax errors like `if __name__='main'` and `format(n    ame)`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`myList` should be `my_list` by PEP8.

Add PEP484 type hints.

`from bisect import bisect_left` should be moved to the top of the file.

I think it's clearer, rather than `image.getdata()`, to just use the `np.array()` call on the image file. That way you can `min` and `max` on it without converting it to a list.

I don't see a lot of value in defining a local function `chunks` that you only call once and has only one line (the import not counting; that should also be moved to the top).

`avals` should not use a `range`, and should just `zip` over the two sub-series.

You should extract from your main code a conversion function that neither prints nor saves to a file.

### Suggested

```py
import PIL.Image
from bisect import bisect_left
import numpy as np


CHARSET = (
    "@$B%8&WM#*oahkbdpqwm"
    "ZO0QLCJUYXzcvunxrjft"
    "/\|()1{}[]?-_+~<>i!l"
    "I;:,\"^`'. "
)


def closest(my_list: list[int], my_number: int) -> int:
    pos = bisect_left(my_list, my_number)
    if pos == 0:
        return my_list[0]
    if pos == len(my_list):
        return my_list[-1]
    before = my_list[pos - 1]
    after = my_list[pos]
    if after - my_number < my_number - before:
        return after
    else:
        return before


def resize(image: PIL.Image.Image, new_width: int = 300) -> PIL.Image.Image:
    width, height = image.size
    new_height = int((new_width*height/width)/2.5)
    return image.resize((round(new_width), round(new_height)))


def to_greyscale(image: PIL.Image.Image) -> PIL.Image.Image:
    return image.convert("L")


def pixel_to_ascii(image: PIL.Image.Image, light_mode: bool = True) -> str:
    pixels = np.array(image.getdata())
    direction = 1 if light_mode else -1
    charset = CHARSET[::direction]
    minp = pixels.min()
    maxp = pixels.max()
    lst = np.arange(minp, maxp+1)
    lchunks = np.array_split(lst, len(charset))

    vals = [chunk[0] for chunk in lchunks]
    avals = dict(zip(vals, charset))
    ascii_str = ''.join(
        avals[closest(vals, pixel)]
        for pixel in pixels
    )
    return ascii_str


def convert(path: str) -> str:
    image = PIL.Image.open(path)
    image = resize(image)
    greyscale_image = to_greyscale(image)
    ascii_str = pixel_to_ascii(greyscale_image)
    img_width = greyscale_image.width
    ascii_str_len = len(ascii_str)
    ascii_img = ""
    for i in range(0, ascii_str_len, img_width):
        ascii_img += ascii_str[i:i+img_width] + "\n"
    return ascii_img


def main() -> None:
    ascii_img = convert('archived/image2l.png')
    name = input("enter the image name here: ")
    with open("{}.txt".format(name), "w") as f:
        f.write(ascii_img)
    print(ascii_img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Output

``````````
                       IxL00QOqW%Q)I...    .                .   .``',~tCd****#MW&%%%%&*d0c/?~<i!I;;:,""^`'``'....'...'''````^`'... ....''    .'`'.                                                                                                                                                          
                       ln0ZOQ0wMBO\!'``                     .      ..`:~(vma**o*#W8%%%BB%MdUr([-+>!I;;I;:,"""^'''```````^^^^"^`'`'''''.''     .'''.                                                                                                                                                         
                       ;xQZOCQm#8Zti'`'                              .'^^;+\Uq*M##*#MW8%BBB8*pUf([_<!I::,,,,,^```^"^^^^`^^^^^``''''''..'`      .....                                                                                                                                                        
                       IrQqwQ0wMBwj>',".                                `"^^:~|cZk##*ooM&8BBBB8#pUt}?+<il;:;I;:"^"","^^"^^^^````'``''. '`        .''.                                                                                                                                                       
                   .   ,\UqpO0m#Bqri."".                              ....'`^``,<(vmoWWM##W8%BB$$8bCr([_<illI;:"^^^^^^","^^^`````````. '''...   .'''.                                                                                                                                                       
                       ")XdkmZq#8dc+'""'.                                     .'^^,<(Xqa####M&8%BB$%MdUj1-<>>!I,^```^^^"^^`''.''.'''.  `^`'.. ....''.                                                                                                                                                       
              ..   .   ^{cpkmmqo#mn<',,.            ..                          .^,,,;~(u0kM&WMMWW8%BB8a0u|}-<!lI;:,,"^`^^````.    .'..`^`'   .''.....'.  ..           .     ...                                                                                                                            
....      ......       ^1cqdOOwkaOx<`,".     .                              ..    .`"I!Il</Qa%8M*o#M&%B%8Ma0v\[+<ilI;:"",,"^""`'..'''..`^. .... .``'.... ....  ..                                                                                                                                           
..                     '_xmpQ0w*&qu+^;:           ..''.                              `,;li]fO&%&8888WW8%%BB%8owv([_~>!;"""``^^^``^^`'`^'.....'. .''..      ....''..`^,;l>+{|frxnnuvr\{_l"""^`.                                                                                                              
11{{1)))1}]?---__-___-_1uZ**pqbW$#mzft\(1}[[[})|/rcCOJj?"`'                             `;-fLaaaWB$$B%%%%8W&%BB*qUx\[++?}1|/tfjxuvvvvxjf\}_<iI:"```,l<-]]-<;^"I+1fvYJLQ0QLQQCUXzzzzUQO0LX\+:`'.       ..                                                                                                    
bbbbdddddpppppppdbkaahhaoo**oaa#&W#abbdddddbkkkbbkk#$#C|;,,'                              I|L*ada#MWB$$$$%8&&W&%B8MkZCOpqwZ0CYczYcxvYUC0wkbmX|{1\xcJOZQLQLJLOmwqqZ0CXuxxf/|)1{}[]][][\vmakOx(1{{]+!:^'''..   .                                                                                              
bbbbdppppdbbbdbkbppqpddpqwmmwZOmqqwwwqqqqwqqwwZOOZmdobL\:^^.                  ..    .     I\O8MbbkbkoM%$$$$B%&W&8$$$&hq0Yurt|))))1{{{11)|xYmbhbwwm0Jznt//|(fzZbkqzf/|){}}}{{[[[[[[???)rUZqq0LCL00Q00CXr(]>:^..''.........                                                                                   
00QLLQ000OOZO0000QQLLLQQQQ00OOOOO00OOOOZZOZmZO00OZwdhbOf!::`.                             !jm&Waaakka#B@@$%88B$$8#bOYnt|(()1{}}}{}}{11{{|uQbkqCnf\||()}[{{1}}(/jf)}{}}[[[[[[]]???]]]][[{1111{{{1)\/jcC0ZZJj}!:,"^```'.....''......                                                                          
mZZOOZZmmmwwwmmwqqqpddbbkkkkhhahkbbkhbddppqwZZZmmwmqbdZfI,:`.                             ijw%Wao#&8&Wokq0COd##qJvj/()}]??]]]]]]]][[]--1fzYcr|1}[][}{{[]]][[][[[]--][[[]]]]][[[]???]]]][}}[]]???--][]?])uCwC/_;^```^`..``^`'''...     ...                                                                   
#######MMMMM####MWWWMM#*********oaao**#W%B8#bmqdpqmmppZt,`"'                              !fm%8M%BWk0XnjfnYwkOzt()))11}[}}}[[[[[[}{}]???]]]??]][]?][[]???][]]]]]]??]]]]]???]]]]??------???????--????]]?-+)zQ0u}i,^^^^.'^"^``..`````''''....   . .       ..                              .                   
pppqwwwwwwwmmmwwwqqwmmZZZZZZOZZmmZZmmmqb*%B8awqpqmZmdp0/,^,`                              !fw$@@8oLuf\\||cmmLx|()1{{}]]]}}[]]][]]]]]]]??????]]]]????[}]]?]]??]]]]]][[]???]]]?-------???????????-?]]]?-]?__?tC0Ct~I:"^`````''..'''''''............................                   .....                   
zzXXzzzXXXzccczXYUJJCCJUUUJJCCLLLLQ0OOZqhW8&hwqqwOQ0mqZjI,:`.                          .  ixp$@&pUx/|){{(tj/(1{11}}}[?][[]]]??]]]]][[11[?????????-??]]]?-__--???]?]]??---?????----?]]]]?????]]]??????---]?~?\YqOc1lllI:"`'...''```````'''````'..'''''''.''''..'''..................... ...              ....
czzzzccczzzzzXXXXXYUJJCCCJJJCCLLQ0000Zwpa&8&apqqZ0LLOmZf:":^.                        .,>}jXZ*BWpXff/)}[[}}[]???-?[]?][[]???][[]]?????]]?---------?]]?-??--_--??]]]??-------??]]]???]]]]]???]]]]?]]]]--]}}}}[[\cwokwOQCXx\}+!I::,,,,,""^^```^^''''''''''''..''''''''''``'''''''.'...........                 
YYXXXzvccXXXzXXXYUUYYUJCCJJJCCLLLQ00OZwdo&%8aqqqmOQQQZZj;,;"'.    ..              `l?jXUUXux0#kLj1))1{}[[]]???--?[}]]]]]]]??]]]?--????????????????--?????--??????]]]]]???---???]]]?--????--?]]]????????][[]]]][)/jxrxzJ0wqOYj1~!lI,"^^"^`^^^````'''`''`^'..'```''````""^`^``''''....''.'''.                 
UYXzzzzczXYYYXXzXUUYYUUUYUCLLLLLLLQ0OZmpa&%8aqqqwOCJLZwx!;I"'.                 ."-fJmLzj|11|cZJr([}{}[]]]]??]???]]]?]]]]]]???]]?--??????????????-------????]]]??-????-----------???----???--?]????]]]]??]]??----?]]]?_-}(fcLZZJn1~l;:::"^""^^""^^^^^^`^^`'```^"^```'`^^^``'''...........''.......     .     
JJYYXXYYUUJJUUYYYUYXYYUUUUJJJCLLLLLQ0Omqa&%8hmmmZ0CJQwpxI,:"'.                `?nLZUr)[{{[]]}1}]][[[]?_-]?--?--]]??????]]?--?]??---????????????-------??---????---???-----------????---?]?????????][[]]]]]]?--?[}]??][[[[[?]|nJOOLct?>!I:;I;:,"^^^^^^^^^`''''`^^'````^""^`'''.....  ....''.........   ......
JJJUYYYUJJUUUUUYYXXYYYUUJJJJJCCLLLCLQ0Zwh&%&hmZmZ0CJLZmj;,;"'.               I|YwLx([}}]][[?][[[[[??][[]]??????[]??]]?????--???-__---??????--------------__----??]]]????????????????--?]]]???]]]?-?]?-___-----?][]???][}[??]??](nCqmX\~!!ll:,::,","^""""^````^"^```''^^^``'''..'..  ....''''''...........   
JJJJUJJJUYXYYYYYXXXYYUYYUJLLLCCLQLCLLQOwa8%WhwwmZOQLQZmj:^,^'.             ^<jqpJx()1{}??[[?][[[[[??][[]--?--??]?]??-_-???---??-__----???-------------??-__-------?????-------????--_--?----???-----__--??-___?]]?----??][}{{}?_+{rJwz]>!lI;:;:,,:,"","^^```^""^^^^``^^''''`''''.....'.''''''''''...........
CCCJJCLCUYYUUUJJJJUYUUYYYJLLCCCLQLCLLQOwh8%WappqZ0QQOwqr;`^'.           ';}nm*Mmx/|()){[]][}[?????-----_-?]?-????]]?-------_----__-------------_______---------___-???-______--???-_________-----???------_____------??-?]\vC0Xx/|/Ya0(+i;:::;:,,""^"""^``'`^^^^^^`'`^^``^^`''``'''''''''``````'''''''''````
LLCCUJJJUJJJCCCCCLCJJCUYUUJJJCLQQLLQ0Omqa88MhpqmZ0QLQZZf,'^.   ..     'l|vzUOqpU\)(1[[[]???]]???????]??---???-_--------_____---------___-------___+__------___+____--??--_-???-?????--__+____--?-___-----------_+-?-------+-/XmpCcnQWm)<lII;;II;:,"^"""""^```""""^``^"""""^`'`""^```````^"""""^^^""^^`^^^^^^
CLLLCCCCCCCCCCCCCJJJCCCJUUCCCLQ00QQQ0Ompo8&obqwmZ0LL0ZOt"'`.         .+fUCx/\/t([}{[]]??????????????????-???????---_-??------------?-_++___--------___------_____----?????]]]??-?????--------_________---------___---?--?[]-+]x0baddbX}+<!IllI;:,""",,,,,,"",,,"^``^,,,,""""","^```^,,"""""""^^^",,,"^"",:::
QQQQLLCCCCLLLLCCCJCLLLLLLLQLCLQ000Q0OZwpo%8*bqwmOQL0wmL('."`.       `ijJvt({[?--?[[?-]]??????-?]]??-?????????????-_-?]?-----?????????-___--------_____-------__---?????????]]]??]?----------______---------________--?--?[[[_+?/Qa&bu1+~_<!I;;;:,,,,,::::::::;;;:,,,,:,,:;I;;;,"""^";II;,"^"""^^":;I;:::::::
QQQQQQLLLLLLLLCJJJCLLCCLQQQLCLQQQ00Zmmqd*B%*kpwmmZLOdpC1 .,'       `-rYUt}{1}[}]??]]??]]]????-??]]?-?????????????----??-------????????]]]]]]????-____---???-------?]???????-??]]]?---???????----___---??????----??-__??-?]]]]]+-|XhhCt+<+ill!I;;;:::::;;;;;:::;;::::::,,:;;;IlI;;:::III;;;;II;;;;III;;;I;;;;
00QQQLLLLCCCLLCJUUJCCCCCQQQLLQ000OOmmwqb#$8adwmZZ0COapX[ ','      :[vOUj)}))}[]]]]]-_-?????]??????????--???--__????-__-----------------????]]]]?????????]???------???--???---??]?-____---???????-__--?]]]]]]?????--??????-???-??_(YpoQ1+<!l!!II;;;;;;;;;;IIII;::,",:::,,:I;:;lIIIl!!III;:;l!!lllII;,,":;:,,,
OO000QLLQLLLLLLLCJJCLLLQQQLQ00OOOOZZmmqkM$&hdpwZZ0CmMpr~.'"'      >jUCj[}11{]?]]]]]?-----??]]?????????---??--_--???-_+_---____-------__-----------__?]?]????--------__-?]]]]?]]??--------????]]]]????]]]]]]?-------------?????]]])rZB8qz\[+~<!lllII;::::;;;;:::::;;;;;:;;;::;Il!!!lI::;;:::IIII:,,,"",,:;;;;
OOZOO0Q00O0QLLLLCCCLLLQQQQQ0OO000OZZmZwkM@%obpwmZOCwMw/i..'.     `{YUu|]{1[?-??][]]??????]]]]]]]]]?---_-????????--__++_------_____----_----??---__+__-_____--???--____-??]]]]]???------??--?????][]]???????--__----???????]]]]?--](UW$8bJt[_~il!llI;;;;;;:,:::;;;;I;::;I;,:IIII;;;::::;;II;II;:,,,,,,,:;IIII
ZO0OOOO00QLLQ00QLQQQLLLLQ000Q00OOOZmmmqbM$%obqwZ0QLqWq\i'       .:/ZJt)}11]----?]?-__-??]??]]??????-----?????????----____-???--____-?-----??????????---------?????-_+_____--------__---??????????]???---????----?????]]]]][[[]]??}\U*&*aqj+~<!llIIIII;;::::I!!llIIIIIIIII:,::;;;;;;;;;IllI;;I;;::::::::;Illl
ZZOOOOOOO0QLQ000QQQ0QQLLQ000000OZZZmwwqd*$%*kqmO0QCwWpf+^        `(0Ln|[[[?-___---__--???---------______-----??????]]]?-----???----------????????]]]----------__________________--___-------?--????-----????-------------??????]?1jCbakobx~<<>i!llIII;;;IIl!!!llIll!!!lll;;Ill!!!llIII;;;;:;;;::::::,,,::;;;
ZZZZO0QOZZOQLQQ0QLQ00O000OOOO0OZmZZmwqpdo%8#kqmZZ0UZMpr+'         -zCYf}}}]-___----????????---------????????----------??------?]]?--_----______---??-_--------??????---_______-------______--?????--------??------------??????]?-?1\fYmdmti><>i!!lll!!llllll;IIIIll!!lllllIIIll!!llI;;;;;;;;;::,,:::,,,,:;;;
ZZZZZO00000QQ000QLQOZZOOOOOO00OZmmmmwqpda88MkwmmmOJmWdr~  .   .   itYLx1)(}]??]][]?---?-??????-----???]]]]??--________-??------?????-????--______---___-----____------___________________---------_____--????---------????????]]]-~_{zbqY)!!!IIIllI;;;;;;;;;;IlI;;;;;,,:;!l;;;;II;;::;;;IIllI;:,:;;;;;;II;;;
ZZZZmZZZOO00000QQQQ0OOOOZZZZZOOZZmmwqqpdo&8WkmmmmOCw&bx_'.`.      I)Ywc))1[????][[[]????----______----?????-----_____--?------------????-----___--?----????---____-____________________--??--____--_-__-----_--------??--??---???-+1vqWO\->iii!lI;::;;;;II;IllII;;;:,"",:;;IIIIlIIII;IIllllIII;::;;;;IIlIIII
OOOOOZmZZ0QQ00000O00OOOOOOOOOOOZZZmwqqpb*8%&hwmmZ0CZMdn?^.'.      "_vwz(1{[?---?][{[]??_______----?????????]]]??-____--___--------___--_++++++++__--------_____________--__-??--?--_____----__++-[?------____-?--__-???-----__?}1)(zhowx_<<i!!l;::;;;;;;;IIIII;;;Il!!lIII::I;:l>ii>>>i!!!lII;IlI;IIIIIII;:::
ZZmmZZZO00QQQLQ0OO0Q0OOOOZZZZZOZmwwqqqqdo8%8aqwwZ0Lmoqu?. ...     ;1Xwc1[]??--???][]?----????????????????]]]??-__+______-----------______+++_---____--_+++++__-______+______--__----___++______+-]?_______----------???-------[\zOb*#Of[<<~illlIIl!ii!lllllIll!lllliiiiii!i>!I!>>i!!l!ii>i!!lIII;:;I;:;IIIII
ZZmmmZOOOOOZO000OZO0OZZOOZZZZZZZZwqppppdaW%B*qwwmOCZopu?. .      `1CQYf{{{[?---???]]?-_----------------___--___++++__---??-______-?---?-___--?????-________--------_______________---__+++__--___---------__---??---???---??---(UphZr{~<~>lI;;;;Il!llIIIl!!i>>>i!!>~+~<>>><~<<>><~<>!iii!ii>>>ii!I;II;Il!!!!
ZZZZOOZZZOOOZZO0OZO0OZZZZmmmmmmmmwqpddddhM%$*qqqmOJOapc]..^'    ^+udC\)111[??--?]]?]]?-??????----------____--_____-?????---______--???--__---__-???-+++_----_______--__-_______+__----_____---____-?-__-]1||1[-?]?-???----????-(JZJtl,!!!!lII;;IIl!!!!!iii!i<<>i!!i<<<<<<<<~+_++~<>ii!!!ii>>>>>>i!!!!!ii!lll
qqwmZZZZZZOZOOOOZZZOZZZZZmZmmmmmwqppppdbaM%B*qwwwZLZapz[..^'    >nL0n[}1}?]]]]?][]?????]]]]]?]????------__--???------?-___--------___---???--___--??__----------__-------______+__??-__-????-------?-_---\CCu/}]]?????----??-?|zb*qJrtt////tft//ttffrncYCLQ0OO0QCCCLQZmqqmZZmmZOO0CJJYzvxf\(()1{}{{{{}[[[]]]
qqwwmmmmZOOOZZZOOOOOOZZmmmmmmmmwwqpqqqpbaM%B*qqqmZ0mkdC(^`"'    -LOXj{[[?-]]?--?]?????]]]]]?????---?-??-_+__----____---__------??--_---]]]?-_+_--])tnx1?-_+_-____++------_-?---???][{1)}]?????????--____+|L0zf1[[?-?]]]?]]?]1j0hohpph*W&&#ahhbdpddbkkbkkkkbbkkkao*#MM*oabpwwwqqqkoaaoM%%&*hddkahaoooooaaaaaa
mmwwwmZZZZZZmmmmZOO0OZmmmmmmmmmmwqpppqpdh#%$#pppwmOmkkZfI"^'    ]O0x|{}[-_??----?----?]]]]??????----???-_++______+___--______________++_---_++__+_)vaaj??--][{1}]--_--_-)jcXf1[???[tzUXf1{}]?]]]?_--??+-|vmQr([][???]]]]-_[/YpMMqCXzJZhMMdO00LCCCCLLLCJUUUYYYYXYJCL0O0QLCCCJCCCCLCJYYJObM%@@$%Makbbbbbbbdppp
mwqqqwZZZmmwmZZmZZOOOOZmmwwmmmwwwqpqqwqdh#%@#ppqwm0wahZj!:,'   .)pwx|}}[?-??--??----?]]]????????????------?????---------______-----__------??-?]++|X*oj-_?1xJCXf)1}--}\nUQJu|[}]_[/UdZz/}}}[[][[]?---}/vQ0Ux)}}]--?---]1tzOk#Mkw0Q0QJOkoaOYJCCJUUUUJJJJCCCLLLCCCCLQQQ0QLLLLLLLQ0QQCJJUYJ0kWMhwQLLLCJCQOOQLLL
mwwwwmZZZmwwwmZZZmmZOOOZmwwwmmmwwqpqqqpbh#%@#qwmmOLZabJ(,^"'   .(bm/1{[?--??????----?]]]???????????----_+_____+++__------_____-----__-???----___]|YqbOt}1jJwpUt1]?]{tU0OYf)]?-_-[j0pwu[?]]???]?-__-1rUOOYx({}[]-__?1\rUp*8&opO0QQLCUYZohmYuXJJJUUUUJCCLLLQQQLLLLLQ0QQ00QLLLLLLQ000LCCCCJCp#aqQJQQLQQQQQQ0000
wwmmZZZZZmmmmZZZOOZZZZmmmmmmmmwwqppqqqpbh#%@MdwZZOQmodX1:,:`   .(kwt)1]-__??--??----?]]]????????????-----??]???--_____---__++_----______+___+~+[x0bdz/1/YmkOn|})\fvOqmYt){}[?_+1u0dLf}+?[-_-?}{)fcQqdwUnt|()(\juXUQqh#MMadwOQQ00QLJUJw#amJzJCUUYYYYJCLLLCCLLQLLLCLLLLLQQQQLCJCLQOO0QQLCCQd*hqO0OOQQ0QLLLQQQQ
ZZZZOOOOZZZZZZZO00OOZmmmZZZZZZmwqppqqpdbh*8@WkqZZZOqapY(I,,'   ^/opf1}1)[???----?---?]]]]???????----???????----_+++++_--__+++__---_++_-_+~~_{fUd*#bZLQp*&#dLzYLOmdqLv/{--?-]1tYmahOzjnzvnnuzUCJULZb*M#kpppqqqpdhooabpmOQQ000QQQQQQLLLq*odOCLQLLLCJJJCLLLCCLLLLCCCLLQQLCCLQQLCCLQQQLLLLCL0dapOLLOOQLQLLCCCLLL
ZmmmZO0OOZmmZOOOOOZZmmmmmmZOOZmwqqqqqqpbh*%@&adwqwmqapY(;``.   .}mwc\[}{}]]]?--???????]][]]??----?]?---__++++______+__---_--??----_-----[|xJ0O0CYzccunucYYXU0bMMawJr/fjxvzUL0Zwm0CUUUJJYcvnrt\)[+>?/UqbbwZZOQQQLLLLCCCLQQQQQLLLLLLLCCmhbw0CCCCCCCCCJCLLLCCLLCCCLLLLLCCCLLLLLLLLLLLLQQQQQOdap0CJLLLLQQQ0QLCCC
wmmZZOOZZmmmZZZZO0OZmwqwmZ000OZwwwwqqqpdh*8@&hqmqqZqadC|;""`.   <uCUj}}1{}[]]]]]????]]]]][]??---????-_______________---____-??-__+~+-[\cQZ0Xj1+!lllI;::;I;;I!+}|fnzUJUYzcnj\1-<!llllllllIIIIIIIII;:;~(z0ZOCJCJUCQLCCCCCLLLLLCCCCCCLCUQpdpOCJCCCCCCCJJCCCJJLLLCCCLLLQQLLLLLQQQQ0000OO0QQQOk#dQCCLQQQLLLQQLLLL
wwwwmZZZZmmmmZZZZZZmmmwwmmZOOZZwqwwqqppdko8@8odqppmqabQ/l,:^``. 'l1r/[[[]?-??]]???????---???-__-????]?--__----__------??----?]----[\nYJXr)-<ii!lllI;IIllII;;IIIIIl!>>i!lllII;;;;;;:::;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:,:<)zOpwLJUJLLLQQLCUJLLLLLCUUJCJYLqhhZJJCCCCCCJJJCCCJJCCCLLLLLLQQ00QLCQ00QQQQ000QQQQZaWdQLLQ00QQQQQLLQQQ
wwwwwwwmZZZmmwwmZZZmmwwwwmmZOZmwqwwqqqpdbaWB8#kppqmpabL/l::`..  ^</Xr[?]???????]]]]??------__---??]]????_--------????---????]]_+?tU0Lu(_illllI;:::;;::;;;Il!!lIIIIIII;;;;;;;IIIIIIIIIII;;;;;;;;;::;;II:;</QqmQYXXJLLLLCJLQQLCJCLCCCJYQphhOUJCCCLLLLLLLLCJJJCCLLQQQ000QQQQQ0O0QQLCCLQ0000ZhMqCJCLQ00QQQLLQ0QQ
mmwwwwwmZZZZmwwwmZZOmwwwZZZZZZmmwqqqqqqdbhMB8#bwqqZwkdQ\;,;^'   ,]fct_?}}}[]???]]]??----?]?-???---??---------------??----?]?+_[tUQJj-il!!I;IlI;:,,::::;;;;:;;II;;;;;;II;;:::;;III;::;;IllllII;;;IlIIlll;,l[uwwQYcYCCCCCLLLLCUUJCCJJUYQphk0YJCCCLLCLLLQLLCCCCLLQ0000000Q000000000QQQ00QQLQd*qCCCQ000QQQQQQQQQ
qwmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmZZOZmmmZZmZZZmmwqpqqwqdbb*%%WbZwwZmbpL(``;,`'  ,?fXr}{))1}[[[[]]?????????]]??????--------___--------?--?]__-|YQCr?i!!i!llI;;;;;;;;;::::;;:::::,,;;:;III;:::::;;;::::;;;IIIII;;;IllIlllII:,+fCqOJUUJJJJJJUUUUUYYUUYYYLwkh0zJLCCLCJJJCCCCLLLLLCLLLLLLLLQQLLLLQQ0000QLCCCLOb*dOLL0O00QQQQQLLLL
mwwmZZZwwwmmmwwmmZZZZZmmZZO0OOZmwqqwwwqdbk*&%&kmqqOZdqJ(^'"`.   "_jJu)11[]??]]]??---??-__--??----__-?]]]----____________-?_}rY0z}>l!i!IIII;;;;;;::;;;;:::::::::::;;::;III;;:;;;:,::::::;;;;;;;;;IIIIIlII;:::I)XZqLXYUUUUUUUYYYUUYYUYXU0pbQzUCCCCCCJUUUJCCCLLCJJJCCLLLLLCLLQQQQQQQLQLCCCLObodOQQ00QLJCLLLLCCC
wwwmZmwwqwwwwmmmZZZmZZmZZO00OZmmwqqwwqppdkoM%8bOwqZwkpC(^^;`    .:(Jc|{]+~_-?----__----__------------???--___---__++++_-++?/Q0j[il!!lI;;;;;;;;;:::;;;;;;:::::::;;;;::;;;;;;;;;::,,::::::::::::::::::::::;Il;:I-vqqZJXXXUJUUYYYXXzzzXXCZqqCcXUJCCCCCJUUJJCCCCCCJCCLQQQLCCCLLLQQQQLLLLLCCLOpbZCJCLLCJJLQQLLCCC
pqwmZZwwwwmmmZZZZmmmmmZZZO0OZZmmwwwwqpppdbaM%%bOwwZmdqC)`"l^ ..  .-cJXf1{}[]]]?---??]]]]]??---------???-__-----_____+++++]tzLz]!iii!l;;;I;;;::;;;;::::::;;;;;;;::::;;:::;;;;;:::::;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:;I;:::;;;Il;;]j0pLXccXYYYYUUYXYYXXYQpdwCzYUUUJJJJJJJJJCCJJJCLLCLLLLLLLLCCCLQQQLCLLCCCLOdhmLLLLLCCCCCCCCCCC
ppqmZZmqpqwmZZZZZmmmmZmmmZOOZZmwwqqwwqpddbh#&8kmwwOZpwL|"^:^..    ;1Xmc()1[???---???????---??????--_------_______________{XQc\<l>ilI;;;III;;;;;;;;;:::::;;;;;;;::::;;::::;;;::::;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:;;I;:;II;I!l;;<umZQXczXYYYYYYYUUUXcCqdqLXUCUUJJJJCCJUUUJUJJCCCJJJJJJCLLCCCCCLLQQQQCJJLOdhmJJCCCCJJUYJCCCJJ
wwwmOOZwqwmZZmmZmmmmZZmmwmZZZZmwqqwwwqpdbbh*&8kZmwqdhkO/,";"'.     "\LXf{-][?-----?---_-_--?]]]]?-___----______+___---_-[tmpt~>iil;;;;;IIII;;;;;;;;;::::;;;;;;;:::;;;;::::::::::;;:::::::::::::::::;l!I;IIIIII;:l|zOZYczXXXzXXXXXXXzzLqpwJcYJUUUUUJJJJUUUUJJJCCJUYYYYYUUUUUUUJJCLQQLJUUCOdk0XXYJJUUUYUJLCCCC
mmmmZZmmwmmmmmZZZmwwmZmmwmZZmmwwwwwmwqppdbh*8BhZmwwphkmt,";,`'.     ~fULr1)1}]?-??????-??????]]???--____++______-_--___?{fwdf+<i!lllIII;;;;III;;;;;;;;;;:::::::;;;;;;;;;:,,,::;;;:::::::::::::::;I;:;II;;;;;III:;>)JmCYzzzzzXXXXzzcvcJmwZUcXUUUUUJJJJUUUYUJJYYYYUYYYYYYXXXYYUUUUUUUUXXYC0dhZUYYUUYYYYUJCCCCC
wwZZZZmZZZZmmZZZZmwqwmmZZZZZmwqqqwmmmwqppdh*%$hZwqwpbbwt^^;"'.      ^+XpX\(1[?---????-_-????----------_________----___~+[tOm|>i!lI;;I;;;;;;;;:::::;;;:::::::;II;:::;;:::::::;;:::::::;I;;:;;;;;I;;:::::;;;;;;;;;;;_uQ0LXczXYcvczccvvvCwqOUvXYYYXXYYYUUUUYXYYYXXXYYXzzXYUUYUJJUUUYYXXXYUJLqhmJYYXXYXXXYUUUUUU
pqmZZmmmZZZZZZZmmmmmmmmZZZZZmmwwwwwmmwppdbh#B$*pppppdbpj,";^..   .   `t0Lv\{}[?------__-??-______--??-?_+++__+++~~~++_~~}jOZ\<>ii!lI;;::::::::::::::;;;::::;IIII;::;;:::::::;;:::::::;I;;::;;:;I;:::::::;;;;;;;;I,itY0LvuvccvvccvvvvuJqqZUvzYYXzzzXXXXXXzzXYXXXXXXXXXXXXzcXUUXYYUUYYYYUYYOpQzcvczXXXXXYYYYYY
qwmZZZZZOOOOOOZmmmmZZZZZZZmZZZmmmwwwwqpdbka#B$oqppqqpdqr:";^'.        )XJc|}1{]-__-___-?]]?-____--??--__---___________~+1xmw\<i!!lIII;::::::::::::::;;::,,:::;;;;::;::::::::;;::::::::::::::::;;;:::::;;;;;;;;;II:>fUZLnxvunuvvvvccvuUmwOYuczccccczzXzzzcczzzXYYYXzzzXXzzzXYUUYYXXXXXzzXUOwCvnnuczzzXXXYXzzz
wwmmZZZZZO000OZmmmZOOZZZZZZZZZmmmmmwwqpdbho#%Bhmqpqpkhdn!;I"'. ..  . .?rYz|[}[-__---?]][[[]?-____----__________--__+~~<+[fZw\>>i>!;II;::::::::::::::::::,,,,,::::::::::;:::::::::::::::::::::;;;::::::;;;;;;;;;II;~rJQXttxxxxnuvccvvcJmqZYnczcvvvvczzzzccvuvccczzccvvuvvvuvvcXzzcczzcvuvX0wCcvczXXzcvvvczXXX
mmZZOOOOO0QQ0OZZZZZZZZZZZZZOOZmmZmmmwwqpbka#%$hZwpwpboac>II,`'.      .l1XJ/[]?-------?]]?---______---??-__-----_+~~~~~<<_|Opr?+<>l;;;;::::::::::::::;:::::::::;;:;:::::;;:::::::;;::;:::;;;;;I;;::::;;;;;;;;;;;II;~xJUcffnxxnnnuvvuuvJZZLzxucccvuuuvccccccvvcccvvuuuuvccvvuvvvvvvcczzcvvcQwCvuuvcccvuvczzccc
ZZZZOOOOO00Q0ZZZOOZZZZZZZZO0OZwmZmmmmmwpdka*%$amwwwwqa#Xi:;^..        `~zQf}]][[[?_++__---------____---???---_++++++++~~<}Cwr]iIIIl;::;;;;;;;;;;;;;:,,,,:::::::::::::::;;:::::::;;;;;:,:;II;;II;;:::;;;;;;;;;;;Ill-cQYutfxxrxnnuuvuuvCqmCznuvvvvvvvzzzcvccvvuvcccvuvcccvvcvuuvvvvvccccvcYOpLvnxuvcvuvvzXXzzz
wmmZZZZmmZOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOZZZZwqqwmmmmmwqdkho8$hZmwwZOkWU>::^'....  .   "xLn\{[{}]?????-__?]?????--------?---_______++~~++[zQz/~lii!lI;:::::;;;;;I;I;;;;;;;;I;;;IIII;;:;III;;;;;III;;;;;;;;;;;II;I;;;;;;;;;;;;;;Ili}zLXujjxuuuuuuccvuvCqmLXuvvccvczzcccvvczcvvvccvvvvvuvczzzcvvvcvvvvvvccz0pQzunvvuuvvvvvzXzz
wmZZZZZmmZZOOOZZZZZZZZZZZZmmmmwwmmmwwwqpbkao%$hZwqwZQb&C~:,"`'...  .   `|zzx1[1[-_--????-----------------_______---___+++]jUOY[i>ilII;;;;;;;;;;;II;l?|rj)]_~ilIl!lI;;I;;;;;;I;::;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;I!+)XLvrjrxnnnnnuvvnnvJZOLzuczcvuvzcvczvvczcvuuvvvvcccvvccvvccccvvuuvvcczXOdQzuuvcvvvvuuuuuuu
wmZOOOOZZZZZZmmZZZZZZZZZZZZZZmmmmmwwqpddka*MB$hZwqwZLd&Q]I"""'...      .~/CU)-]?-----?---______-----------___++__------_+-1nbp/+>i!lII;;;;;IIIIIII;l>]/rruzzv\?<i!lIIll;;II;;;;;;;:::::;;;;;;;;;:,,::;;;IIIIIII;![jQ0ujxnunnnnxnvvunnYZOJvxuccvvvzcvccvuczccczzzcczzccvvvvvvccccvvvvvvvcY0wCvuuuuvvuvvvuvvvv
ZZOOZZmmmmZZOOOOOZZZZZOOOOOOOZZZZZZmwwqdko#W$$awqqm0QdWO(!^""'.         ^-UQt11}]-__-??--??-------_____-]]?-__++______-?_++\dhv{ili!lIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII;Ili~(xvuxf/)+!ll!!lI;;;II;;::;;;;;;;;;;;;:,,::;;IIIIIIII,I)cmmurvvuuuvvunnuuunYO0CcnvzzzcvvvvvvcczzccczzXXXXzcvvccccvccvuunuvcvvXLmqJvcccczzcczzzcccc
mmZZZZZmmZZOOOOZZZZZZZZZZOOOOOOOOZZmmwqpko#&B$*pqwZ0QdMZt<`^"'           IxQQv{__-?-_?]????????------__?[]?-__+_______-?_+<1LqJtiIi!lIIII;;II;;;;;;;II;:,,":l+{\rzcf1~!lII;;;;;::;;;;;;;;IIIIIIIIII;;;;;;;;;;;;"I/JZ0urvvnnuuuuuvvvuuUZm0zrucccvvvvcvuvcccccvccccvvunnnuvvvvccvvuvvvcvnX0wwJvvcvvcccccvvczzz
wwmZZZZZZZOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO0QQQQ000OZmmwqpbh*MB$#dqwmOCq#wx~''^.           'i/OL/}[]?-__---??---????????????-______------_++<[vQLx>I!lI;III;;;;;;:::::,:;;::::::::;i}xvrt|)}_>!III::;I;IIIIIIIIIIIIIII;;;;;;;;;;I:>xQ0JurnuunnnnunnnunxYZmQcrnvuunnuvvvvvvvunnuuuunuuunnnuunuvccvuuvvvvunYmwOYnuvvvvvcvvcczzzz
ZZZZmmZZZmmmZZOZO0ZmwmZOOmdkhahdqwwwwmwpka*#B@owOOwZQq#qu-`",'             IfYCn{?]??--__--??]?---???--??]]?-____-?--?-_-_>-uQOv~I!lII;;IIIIIIII;;;;;;;;;IllllIII:I~}\rzJCj]<!lIIIllI;:IlI;IllI;IlII;:;;;;;;;Ill_zwLcrjnxxrxxnnnnxxrxYmm0XnuvvvunnuvcccvuunnnuuuuuuuvvvvunuvvvuuvvccvvuUZZLznucczzzcvcczzXXX
wwmmmZZZZZZZZZZZZZmmZO0Zk#88&%B&odmwwwwpbho*8BMahoWMbh#dY{",:`..           'Itw0j1??]?-----???--__---____-?----_-??-___-_+~-tUpC}<<!IIIIIIIIIIIII;;;IlIIIllII;;;;;;;;::I]tnccvvr(]~>ilI!i!!lIllIII;;;;::;;;;III![CbLvxrnuunxnuxrxxnnvJww0zxucczzcvuuuvvvuunnuvcvuuuuuvvvvnuccvuuuvczzcvY0Z0XuvzzzXzcvvczXXXX
qwmmZZZZZZZOOZZOOZZZZwph8B#bmbW&#dZmwmwpkaooW%BB$$@$8%%aC1":I^'.             !tvcf{1)}]__???]]?---??-___--___--_+_------??-])vbO(+>lIIlllllllllIIIII!!I;IIllII;;IIIII!!lIl_1|tnXCXf}<i>!!!!ll!!!lIIIII;::;Il!ll>1QbJnuvvvvunvvuuvcvucLqmCcnzXvuccvvvczzzvuvcczXzcvvvvvczcuuvvvvvcccccvvJwwOUcXYXXYYYXXXYXXXX
mZZZZZmmwmmZZZZO00Ommwb*$%bmOp*WWbZmwmwpko*#&%$@$$$@@@@#0/>i!,`'.            .I\Ju)}]?-__-????-----?-__---?-_--__-----????--}xbZ\_i!llllllllllllllll!!IIIl!lIIIllIIl!!iii!l;:""i|ncj?>illl!!!!!!lIIlIIllIIIIl!~)vp*wCUYzcvvvvccvcvnuzLmOJzvXYcvzXzzzzXXzccczzzXzcvvvvcczcvvcccccczzzzzcJmwZJzYUYXYYUYXXYXXXX
mmZZZZmmwwwmZZZmZZZmmwkM$8pOOqhW&b0Ommwdh*#M8$$$$$$@@@@#Zj_<>:^'.  .           [YYx)_?[?????]]????][]]]?-???-]}{{}]-?[]?-_+-1vkm|+>!!!!!!lllllllll!!lIl!!!l!i<~__-?--?-??]?---__?/ULUzuxf([_<i!ll!i>i!!llI;i?/zZh*awQCYcuuuvvcczzzvvzQbqQznvzczYYXXXXXzzXYYXXXzzzzzzzXXzzzzXXXXXYUUUUYY0dbwLYUJUUJUYYXYYYYYY
qwwmZZZZZmmmmZZZZOZZOmkM$%bmZwh&BhZZZZmdho*M8$$$$B$$$@@Mmx]+>;"`.              itYLf-[{[?---?]???][[[[[]-?])fcJQ00Cvf)[]???{fUkO)~>i>>>ii!!llllllll!lIl!!<}jJmkaaooaaooao*######o*W&8%BB8#kmLXuf)?_+<>i+1tuYLOmpbkd0CLQQLCCCUXYYYYXzz0hhwXxzUzzXXXYJJUXzYUUYXzccXXXXYYXzzXXXXXYYUUUUUYY0dpmCYUJUUUUUUUYYUJJJ
ZZmmZZZZmmmmmmmZZOOOOZd*B8pOZqk&@aZZmZwph*M&%@$B8W#M%$@*0/>i!:^'..         .   ,?vOn{}}[]__-][[]]]]]]]]??}\XZQz|(uCmZQ0Omwwpk*WoZ0ZO0OZO000QLJJUYXcvxf/trUpW@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$&qu|}}(nQa%$BW**WB$@$$B$@@@B8#hZQ0QJYX0khdJvYJYzzXXXXXXzcczXzzccccXUUUXzzzXzzzzYYYXYYYYYQqw0YcYJUYJUYYXYUUJJJ
mmmmmmZmmmZZOZZZZ00QL0p*$8qQ0mb&@aZZmZmpko#WB@@$BB%88$@aJ(lII"'.                ,f0Xt)[[]?---?---?]]?-_-]|uwhY(+l!-/LW$@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$B%%$@@@@@@$B&*bqm00mdho#M&W*abpppppdbhM%$@@&hm0wh&$@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$Wp00QUXXCmppCczXzzczzzcccczXXzzzzzzccczXXXXXcczzXYYzzXXzzX0dpOUcXYYYUUUYXYUUUUU
mmmmmmmmmmmZZZZmmO0QQ0p*$8qQ0ZdW@ammmmmqba*M%@@@@@@@@@$aC/+>!:^'                 -nJJf{{[-_---????]]]?-1jQ*B%J\|/xf{/Up#*aaadwZ00QQCUC00Zqdkao#MMMMMMW8%8%B$@@$8aJj)-!l<xZ0z/{1\nYCLCzr\{_[j08@@@@@@@@@$WhZLJLOmOXnrjjuLkB@$&amLLCYXYLmddLvczXzcvvvvczcvcczXXXzcvvczzcczccczXXXXcczXcccQddZJcXUUYYYUUYYYYYYY
OZZZOOOOZZZZZmmZZOOO0Zp*$8pOZwb&@omwqwqbh*M&%@@$@$$8#MMwn];;;^.                  ^~u0ct({{}}[]][[]]]-?}nqW@Baz()xmOr1[fCZwp0j[+>iiil;;;;I!><~~++___+<~]]-|Xb$@$hJ)~_<:":1zQ0v|~;:i}jYQOLz/)fL8@@@@@@@@@8dX(-?|uXv],,"`I1C8@$Md0JUYXXYCmbkLvucXXcvvvvzzcvvczXzzccvczzzvvvcccczXXzcvvvccc0kbmCXYUUUUUUYYUCUYYY
OZZZOOOOZZZZZZmZZZZZZmd*$%dZwqk&@aZmwwqbho#M%@@$@@$&dh&pn]:;;^.                   .[nUYt)()1[?????]]?{f08@@hJt(xJq0/-!<])()]>llI;;l!!llllIIII;;;IllIIIllI?rq@@Bpc1~~<i;"^:[rJ0Ux[i;"",i}fz0d*B@@8*dwa8@&QnfjcLwq0f?-~!>1J8@$*qQJJUYzcUOko0vvcccvvcczzzzzXYYXcccvvcczcccccczXYUYXXXXXYYX0dbqQUJJYYUJJUYJCCCCC
OOOOOOOOOO00000OOOOO0Zd*$%dmwpk&@hOZmwqbh*#M%@@@$$@&dkWqr_":;^.             .      ,]Cwu(}][[]???]]?-)uq$@@wx|jdoLt>!+<lII;;;IlI;Il!!lIIIIIII;;Ill!!lIlll}ud@@Bmx1_~>l;:^'`"!]tncu/}~i>+}\vqM$@@#ZufLoB%bmZJnjjYQn)-i;>(L%@$omQJJJUYXYCb#OunnuvccccvvcvvvczzccvvuvvczzzzzzzXXXXXXXXXUYY0dkbQXUJUUUJJJCCCCCCC
OOOZZZZmZZOO0QQQ00OOOZpoB%hqwqb&$kQZmZwdh*#W%@@@@@$%M8$dx];,"`.                   . ,vmUr1[1{?-_][]?-?)xQk#qz|(UZLn]~~>iI;;;Il!!IIllllIIIIIlllIIIIll!!lIl[up@@Bpz(_~!;::,,"^^`.,-|xunvzJCzYpM$@@oLr/Yb8BhOc/{(jcc)i!I,-vpB@$hOLCJUYXXczmhZYcvczcczcvczcccvvvvvvvczXXXXXXXXYYXXXYUJJCCJULwkh0zUCLLJUCCLLLLLLL
OOOOOOOZZZOO0QQ000ZmZZqaB%kwmmpMBkOmwZZwdaM8$@@@$B8W#&$dn{i;,`..                    ']xLCf((1}]]][[[]?-]1umaaCf1{t\]<llilIIIIIIIII;;;;IIIIIIIIIlllIl!!lII<(0$@@%oQn|]~l:,,"^^`...`,!-)fnXLqW$$@Bdv//Yb%%p0Q0mOJx)+lllI)Q*$@%b0LLCJUYXccQdwQUYUUXXXXXXYYYYXzzczzzXXXYYUUUUUUUUUJCCCCCLLJCQqbZCCLQQCJJLQLCCLLL
OOOOO0OOOOOO00000Q00Q0whBBaqZwkM8kOZmOZqboM8B@$$$$%WaW$pj+"",'.                     .^?U0v/}]}[[?-??--]/XYcXCdpx[<!>]|)-<llII;;;;;;IlI;IIIIIIIIlllII;IlllI>jwM$@@@%Mokpm0LUzvxf//\|||/rYw#B$@@8hLj|/Yd%%p00Zwc[~>>i!>?u*$@%#wCJJJUYYUYX0pqZUzXYXXXXXzzXXXXXzczYYXzcXYYYXXYYYYUJJUUYUCJUUCZpZLJUJJUUJJCCJJJJJ
OO00QQQ00000000OOO00Omdo%B#dZwhWBW**adqdh*&%BBBB$$$%M&%px-,",`.                       ;jJLz\)1[???]??[(zpY}i>tJw0j\rCdJ(_!!!!llI;;II;;;IIII;;IIlllII;;;IllIl~/Up*&B$@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@BaCx(?]xZ&$Maho*qUXXzXJObM$@@&kOJCCJUYXzccQpqOcxvcccccczzXzccczzzYXzzzXYYYYYUYXYJJUJUUUUYXUQdamJYYCLJJJJJLQLCCC
OO00QQQQQ00000OOOOmqaW%B@$8Mo#8$@@@@B*hhoM&%B$$$$@@BMW&pu],,,`..                      `?nwL|}1}[[}[[[\zLLj<!ii?uL00Czr{ilIllIIll;;;::;II;IIIIIIIIIIIIIlllIIIIIl+{|tjuYCQZpka*#W8%$@$$$$%WW#kZzj(]<l!1chB@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$8*d0CJUUYYUXcczLqpmzxvcvvuvvczXYXzzXYXXXXXXXXXXYYYUUUUUYUUJUUYYJ0boZYYULLJUUUUCQLCCC
000QLLLLLQ00000000mbW$@@@$BBBB$B$$@@B*hhao#M8B$@@$B8M%@bn+`^,`.                       .")wmj(1{{{}-]|cpOf]!!ii!!i<<ilI;:;::::;;;:,::;II;;;;IIIIIIIIIlllI;;;;:;III;;;;Ill!iii>>><+_-__]}_<~~>!!lll!I;;</Xmko#MM*akkdqmOLYzzXXXzccczzcvvcULZZXxuuuuuczcczXXXXXYYXXXXXYYYYYYUJCCJUJCLCJUUUJLqhmJJJJJJUUUUJCCCCC
QLLCCCCCLLQQQQQQQ0mbMBBB@%addka&@@@@$8&&WWMWW&%$$B&#hM$bx+^",`.                         !vQCu|(()}_[rQhL[><>i!I;:::;IlII;;;;;;;::::;;;;;;;IIIIIlllI;;;;;;;IIIIIIIIl!l;IlIIII;::;IIllIIIlI;:;;;IlIIII::![uOahmUuuvunnnnnnuvccvvczzzccvvcXCqdCcccccvvccvczXYYYYYYYYYYUUUUUUJJJUUJLLCCJJUUJ0b#d0CUUJCJUUUUUCCCC
LLLLCCCLLLLLLLLQ0Zb#8$BB@B#ahoW%@@@$$$@@@$$$$$$$$BW*aW$dx-,,,`..                        ,1YkQ\)11{]1xLbY~li!llII;;IIII;;Il;;;III;::,,:;IIIII;;IIllllI;;;IIIIIIIIIIIII;;;:::;::;IllI;II!+}(tjrxrrrrt(}-ii-fOkadOmpqm0JzzYYXzcczXYzzXXzccYQhoOXXXYXccczzXXYYXXYUUUUUUJJJJJJCCCJJCCJJJJJUYUQdop0LJUUJUUUJUJCCCC
QQQQLLQQQQQQQLQOmb#B$@@@$$$$$@@@$@@@@@@@@@$$$@@@@%#ak#%du?"",^..                        .:x&ac/{1){|z0qviI<il;;IIIIII;;;;I;;;;;:,:;::::;;;;;;III;;;;IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII;III;;;;I;;,;i?|rvcvxjf/(1{{1{[_<>!II<tOdpCcX0aMawUXYUUUUXcczzXYYXU0o&mXzzXXvcXYYYYUUXXYUJJJJUJCCCJJJCLLCCCJUJJUUYULd*pQUXYUJJJUUUYJCCC
00QQQQQQQQQQQLQZqhW$@@@@@$%B@@$@@@@@@@@@@@@$@@$B%&*hb*8bc?^",^.                           (kWaQx/(1tQwQr>i+>l;;IIIIIIIIIIII;;:::;III;;;I!iilIIllI;IIIIIIIIIIIII;;;IIIII;;IIlll;I>{rczr)-<!i~]1)(()[_~>i!!l:I+\zUUucwo*pYzYUUUUYYYYYYXzvcUbMwJYXXzvzUUUUUJJYYUUJJJJJJJCCCJJJJCCJJCLCCJJCJJqadOCUJCJJCCCCCCLLL
000QQLLLQQQQQL0ZqbM@@$@$$%W&B$$$$$@@@@B88B$@$%*kbbbdpo8pn+'^,`'.                         "|q&$#mcfjXbpn{ii~>lI;II;III;;;;IllIIIIll!~[fXOqqm0Xf}i!i!lllllIIIII;;;;;;lllllIIII;;!}uzx(<IIi}n0hM&&88&MaQn|}]-+>l;!)vOkohZJzzYYYYUCCUUUUYYXXJb#mUzczXzYJJJUUJUUUUJCCCCCLQLCJUJCLLLCJJCCCCCLCCp#hwQCLLLL000QLLQQQ
00QLCCCCCCCCCCLQmb#B@$$$$B88%B$$@$$$@@%okh#%8#bwqppqwa%dn-^,:^'.                        .:|Z#%BMmYXQ*p/+!!i!lIIIIIII;;;;IIIlIIIIIl>}/jf([??]]_>I;I;IIlIIIIIIIIIII;IlllIII;;:;!+|Uc[iIIli[u0pbqwZ0QQLcf)]-~<i!!lIl_|c0pq0JXXYXXXXXXUJJJUYJb#mUzzYUYUJCCLLLCLLCLLLLLQQQLLCCLLLLLLCJJCLQLCCLb#kZLJLQQQQQ0QQQQQQ
O0LCCLLLLLCCCJC0md#B$@@$$B%%B$$$@$$$@@B*hhMB8#kqqqddqo%dx_^":^'                         .;\ma#%BdQZpkC-I!!!lIIIIIIII;;;IIIllllllllllllI;Ii+]?+illi!!!llIIIIIIIlllllIllI;II;;;!+)uu/\\()11)(((()){]?-~<>>>ilIIIllI;;!]jJqmJYYXXYUUUJCLCJUCdomJUUJJJCCLQQLCCLLLLLLLQQQQQQQLLLLCCLQQLLLLCJJLbMpCUUCLLLQQQQQQLLL
00QQQQQLCCCLLLQ0md*%@@@$@$$$$$@$$$$$$@%ohaM%&*kqwwqwZh%dx+`^,^'                          ,\wkboWMM%Mmu?ii!!llIIIIIIIII;;;;;IIIIIIIIllI;:;i(JwwY\]~>illllI;I;;;;;;IIIIl!lIIIIIlIi_{\jrxnxxrrrrrrrnvJ00QCCQQUUUXcr/({-+?xdb0JXXYYUJJJJCJJJQh#wJUUJJJJCCLLLLQ0QQLLQQQQQQQQLLLLLCJCL00000QLLOkMbOOO00QQQQQ00QQQQ
00QLLLCCCLLQQLL0wkoM&%B$$$$B%%B$$@@@@$&hbk#B8#kpqqpwZk%dx_^^"`'                         .:tdhwph%@%kc|}_>!!llI;;;II;III;IIIIIIIIIIllllIII;>(nCCXUYx|?<i!lIIl!lII;IIllIIIIIIIl!ll;Illll!!l!!!i!!!i-uwdqLJOZQQOZmqddddqqkW*q0JJCCCJCCLQLCCQhMpQLLLQQQQQQQQLQQQLLLLLLQQQQQQQQ0ZOQQQQQQQLLLQOhWaqmZO0QQ0OO000000
0QLCCCJJCLQQLCC0wdbbbbhaaaaoo*#W8&&WM*abbhMB&*bqqqqmOk%qt>`^"^'.                         ,thowZq&$kY)~+~>i!llIIIIllIIII;;;;;;;IIIIIIIllll;I>}fnzOdw0QJXur\}]]-+~<i!!!lIIIIII;Ill;;Illl!llll!ii!!li|Uda0XXzcczXYUJCLQQLLQQ0QCCJCCCCCCCCCC0aMwCCCLQ0OOO00000000000000QQ000000O0000000000QLQbWaq0LOO000OZZZmwww
QLLLLLLCLLQQLLCLZpbbdqqqqqqqpdbkahhhkbpwqk#%WobqqwwZOk%m|>"",^'.                         ^\dhmmqM8bU|-_<ii!llllllIIII;;;;;;;;;IIIlIIIIIIllI;l_fJCv)>i>-\X0wm0LLCCQQJXuxxjt/|1[-+>!!!lllIIl!ii>iill?rd&wJUUJJJJCJUUUJUYYYUCCCCLLLLLQQQQQOwM8qLLQQ0OZZO000OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOZZZZOOZZZZZZZZmZOOb#hqZOZZmmwwwmZmwww
00QQQQQLCLQ00QQ0ZwmOQLCCLQQQLLQQLLLLQ00QZd#%WabpqqwmZaBZ1l^^"`.                          ^/kawZwa#*mf[-~i!!llllllIIII;IIII;;;IIlllllll!lIIIll;l_/vcx|1)xZC|>`'`:?XJ|+!i-{\rvJQCUzccvuvzXYvnnnnxj|}?)Q*kZJYUJCCJCCJJCLCCCCCCLLQQQ000QQQQ0moMqQ0OOOZZZO0Q00OOZZZZOOOOOOOOZZZmmmmZZmmmmmmmZZdabqmZOZmwqqwwmmwmm
O0QQQQQLCCLLQLLQLJUYYYYUJCCCCCCJUUJJCLLLOp*%Wadqwwmmwa8L-:`^"'.                          "f*#qwqk*%av)}_>i!!!ll!!llIIIIIII;;;;;;;;IIIll!!lIIII;:l~1fzOk&@WZu)-~_|O0-.      ;rUf1}[}}}\uqbu}]?][1fcXUp**bQUCCLCCCCCCCLLLLLLLLLCQ000QQ0QQ0m*WwL0OmmmZZOOOZZZOOZZOOOOOOOOOOZmwwwwwwmwwwwmZZZb*hpmZmwwmmmmwwwmmm
LLLLLLLLLCCJJCCCJUUUUUCCJJJJJCCJUJJJJCCLOp*%Whpwmmmwp*&C+;:"^'.                          "fo*wwqpk$8Lf[~ii<>i!!!!!llllIIII;;;;;;;IIIIIIllI;;;III;;Ili~-)ruvvcczCqM#Lnf|{<I~\waY)I'.  i|L0?      ~upWaqmOCCLLJJCJJCLQQQLLCCCCLLQQLLQQ00QOq&BdLQ0OOO0QQ0ZmmmOOOOZZZZOOOOOZZZZmmmmmmmmmmmZOOb*#aqZZmmmmmwwqmZZZ
LLLLCJJUJJJCJJJUUUJJJJCCCCCCJCCJUCCJJCLLOq*%#bpwmZZmd#&J~;:,^'.                         .:j**Zmqqk%&0r]i!i>i!l;IIII;;IIIII;;;;;;;IIIIIIllllIlllIIIIl!!llIIIIl>_]}1(truzXzXLwh#WM*bwZZd*WoU/[<:"l\0bkQzXYUUUYYYUUJCCCCCLLLLCCLLLLLLLLLCCQZoMqLCLQQ00000OOZZZO00OOZOO0OOOOO0OZZZZZmmmwwwmmmdo#aw0OZZZOmqqqwmmm
LLCCCCCCCJJJJJUYYYXYUJJJJJJJCCCCCCCJUJCC0q*%#dqwwmZmd*WY>::,"'.                         '!uW*OZppk8&mu[<<>>ilI;;;IIIIIIIII;;;;;;IIIIll!!!!lIIIIlllllIIllIIIll!!I;;;llll!><~_-}|rYCQmd#%B$$B&*kbhW$$%&*dwmZO0QLJJCCCJJJCLLLLCCCCCLQQ00QQQOdkZLQ0OZZZ00Q00OOOO0OOZZZZZZOOOOOOZZZOOOOZZZZOOOqh##q0OOZZOZmwwwwww
LLLLCCCCCCJJJCCUUJJUUUUUJJJJJUJCLLLJJCLC0qo8#bqwwmZwb*MXi::"`'.  .                      'iuW*Ompwqa*kC(??+>!llI;;Il!!lIIIIII;;;;IIIllII;I;IIIIIIllIIllIIIl!lIl!!i!l!lIII;;;I;;;;Ill!>_[1(\tfxvUOkW%$@@$%&WM#obwZ0QCJJJCCLQQQCCLLLLQQLLL0mh*qQLLQQ0OOOOOOZZZZOOZZZmmmZZZZZZmwmZZZOOOOOZZOOwboowQ0OZZZmmmZZmmm
JJJJUYYUUJJJUUUUYYUUUYYYYUUJJJJCCCCUUUUULwo%#dwmwwmqb*#Xi::,^'.                         'lxoaOwdqqba#qr1]+>!llIII!ii!II;II;;;;;IIIIIIIIIIII;IIIIIIIIll!lII!lll!!lll!!llIIlllI;IllIII;II:,:;;;;Il<]\nXYcr({)cbokmLCCJJJCLLQQQQQQQLLLLLCCLOh#pO00QQ00OO00000OZZZZZOZZZOOOOOZmmZZOOOOOOOOO0OOwo#q00OOOOOOZZmmmm
JJUUUJJJJJJJUYYYYYUUUUUYUYYYUJLCJCCCJUYYLwo%#bwmmmmqk*#X<Il:^'.                         .;jhhOwdqqkoMqf}-~i!llIll!!lII;;II;;IlllllII;IIIIIIllllllIIIllll!lIIllllll!!!lllllllllI;;III;;IIIlllllllIIII;;;Il[uw8MdOCCLCCCCCCCLLLQQQQQCCCJJJQdawQLLQ000QLLLQQ000OOOOOO0O000000OZZOOZZZOO00000Ow#8kZO00OOOOOOOOOO
CCCJUUUUJCCJUYYUUUJJUYYYUUYUJJUUUJCLCJUJQq*%MbqmZZZwboovl","^'.                         ';jaamqdddka#wt}]+>!!!!!!!lIII;;II;;l!llllII;IIIIll!!!!!!!i!IIl!!!!!!!ii>iii!!i>i!ll!!ll!!lllllllllllllll!!l!!!?rO&&bZCJCJJJJJUUUJCLLLLLLLLLLLCCQb*dOCCLQQQQLLLQQQQQQ00OOOOO00000000OOOOO0OO00QLLLOaWkm00ZZOOOO0OZZZ
JJCCJJJCLCJUUJJJJUJCCJUYUUJUUUJJJCCCCJJULmo%MhdqmZ0mdaocl"""^'                      .   .IjhamwppdhahQ/[]+>i!llllllII;;IllIIlllllllllllllll!!!lllll!llllIIllllllllll!!!!llllllllllllll!!!!!!llll!i!llll[YdMdXcYUUUUJJJJJJJJCCCCCJJJJJJJUCb#kmLJLLLLCCCLQQQQQLQQ0000QQLQQ000Q0OZOOOOOO0QQQLQkMkwQLZZOOO0Q0000
CCLLLCCLLCCJUYUJCLLQLCCCCCJJJCQLCLLLCUUULwo%WhbqmZOmdaavl:I,`'                          .IjbkZwpqp**wz(]?_~>i!lll!!!lIIl!!IIIl;IIl!!i!l!!!!lllllllllllli~++_-??-+~<>>!!lIII;;IIIl!!!!!!!!iii!!ll!i!ll!l?vq8hXvzXYUUYYXXXXXXYUJJUYYYUUUYXYwhbmLUJCCCLLLLLLLLLCCLLLLCCCCCLQQQLLQQQQQQ00QLLLC0kMhwCJ00QQ0QLLLLL
LLLLLLLLCJJJJUJCCCCCCCJJJUYUJCLLCLLLLJJJ0p#BMbqwmZ0ZpaauI;!:`.            ..            ,-vh*hkhho%WZu(]-~>ii!llllllllIIIlIIII;;IIll!!i!l!!ii!!l!!>~-)uCwba*######hm0LYvuxj/)}?_~<>i!!lll!iiii!l!>!l!!l>{Y&#CXXYUUUUUYXXzzXYUJJJYXXXYXzczOdkpLYYYYUJJJJJJCLLCCCLLLLLLQQQQQQQLLQQQQQLLLLLLCLbodZJULQCLLLLLLLL
QLCCLCCCCCCCCJCLLCCCCCJJUYUJJJCCCLLCCJUULq*$MbpqwZ0OdaavlI!,'.                 ...   ^i)uOb*M&8%$@@&Ou|}?+>ii>>>iiii>>illlIllllIll!!!!!!iiii!!<]tz0doW%%&#ahbqqo&&oZOdhaaooabqqwZQUcnt)1{]-+<ilI!>!liili[z&M0JJZdbpZQCUXULQ0QLCJYYYUUUUYUQmbdQYUUUJCCCJJJCCLCLQLLLQQ0000QQQLCCLLQQLCCLQQLCLdobmJYCQ0wbbdwZOO
QLCLQLCJJJJCCLLLLLCJCLLCJUJUUJCCCCCCJCJUQp#$MdqqmZ0Zk#*cl:I"'.                      `}cd#abqb*W&W#&aYf([+>!!i>><>ii>>iiiii!ll!!i!ll!i!l!!!<]/XwokmQQbokpqqqqqZZh#awznvvuXQhMpCXY0b&%8&##*bwOJvj/|)[-__-(Xd%*CJ0wbaokmJXX0h&8k0JUJJUYUJJYYCmM8aq0LLCJJCCCLLLLCCLLLLLCJLLLCCCLLLLLLCCCLCJUUUCpahmXcCOpko*apO00
LCJCQLCJUUJCCCJJCCCJCLCJUUYYYUJJJJCCCCCJ0p#B#dqqwZQOd**cl;l"'..           ..     ."~\QkakpqpbaM&M**qx){?~<>>ii>>>!!!iiii!!ll!i>>iiiii!ll_fJdkwUf_:,?LapwqqqwmOOk#*b0CLCCma%$h0UCwhM&8%&hmOZpo%$$%Madqqpa88amCOdppbkdmJXUZo8$MbOJUYXXXXzczCqW$%#q0JUJUYUUUUUUUYYUJJUYUJCJJUUUUYYYYYJCCL00LXzQpdwJYQmdkkhk0UUJ
CCCCLCJJJUUJJCCJJJJUCLJUJUXXXYYUUJCCCLCC0p#$MbpqwZQZk*avl:I"..      ..    .   `I-/zZkkbddppddbh*&&*qXr/)[_~>iiii>>>>>iiiii!!l!!i><<>>~{vm#Wh0urr\)(rp#dwwwwmmOZa&#hqqppqoB@$#bpk&B%%B@$*pwwpa%$@$8#a*MMMW#akk*WM*##abwmpaWWM88*kpwwmwmOQQOwbho*#kOQQQQQLLLCCL0mwwmZOOZwdkhdZ00000QLQOb&8#qLZpkbmmdkhhhhbOCLQ
LLLLCJUJLCCJJCCCCCJCCLJJJUYYYUUJCLQLLCCULw*BMbpwZOQma#hu!;I"`'...    .     ';[vOhoohkbbddddppddpdk#WW#hbpLuf\{-~<>i!!!iiiiiiiii>>>>!~/C#@@BW#*###**#88W#okpqwZmo&M##WBB&%$@@$B%B$$BB$$@$$BB$$@@$$BB%%%%%%%BB%BB8&%B8WMW8&Moa*&%$$BBBB%8WMWW#akaW8&*bdpdpmOOmd#B&apmwdoMMW%B%&#abppdkaMB@$8#ooMMooMW&&888M*##
JJJCCJUUJUYUUJCCJUUJJUUUUYXXYYYUUJCCCLLC0pM$MbpwmOQmh*hu!Il,`'...   ..    `+uqWWabdddddbbdddbbdppddbbh*M&8%%&*d0Uzx\)1]_~<<<>><<<i!<{cpW$B&*hbdbbbbkho#W&888WhdoW#aqpho**okdbhookpmwdkaahhkdppqmmwqppwmmqpdbbkkpqbaMWWW#ohbddbko##aaa*W&&88W#aha*WWWWM####*#MWM#***###ohbkh*MW&&MM&8&W**#W&8&&&8%8&MabbhM%88
YYYUUUYYYYYYYUUJUUUUUUUYXXXXXYYUUUUJCCCJ0dM$#dqqwZLZh#oc!:I,`'..     ... ,1zb#okppddddddddddbbdddddpddddbbkkko##MWW#*akdqZCzxft/())tcp&B$%W*ahkkbbbbbbkbbh*W%8&%%*pCYYXzccuxxnczcvuuccczzccvuuuvvvvvvvuuvcczXUUYXYUL0O0LLCCCCCJJCJJJJJJCQQQ0QLLCJCQOwpbkbdqmOQCLOwppqZQCUYXXYJL0OmwqwmOOOO0OOQQ00QQQ00LCQO0Q
YYUUJJJJUUUUUUUJJJUUJCJUYYUUUUYYYYYJJJUYQdW@#pwwZ0J0b*av!:;^'.......   .>/Zoakqqdddpddddpdddppppdbppddppddpddbbbbbkhhh*WWW&8&&WWWWWWWWWWM*akbbbbddbkdddbbbdbaM%$BMdLYYXvvvunxxnuuunuuuuuunnnnnnnuvccvuuunnnuvvvvvccXXYYYXzzzXXYYXzcccvvcccvvvvvvvvuuuvczcvuuvvvvuvczzccvvvcccvvcvvzXzXYYXXzcvzzzcczXYYYXXXYY
CCCCJJJUUUUJJJCCCCCCLLCJUUJCCCJJCJJCCJJJ0bW@MbqmOQCQqa*X>"^^`''`'.   '^>up##bppddddddddbbddbbbbbbbddbbbbbddbkkkbbbbbbbbbddddbkkkkhahkdpbkkbbbkkbdpdbkbddbbkbdkoW88oZCJXcccvvuuuuuunnuuvuuuuuuvvuuvvccvvvvuuvvvvnnvzXYYYXzzXXYYXzzzccczzzzzccvcccccccccccvvuvvczzzcczzzzzzzXYYYYXXUOwwOCUXXXYYUYzczXXzvzXzzYU
QQQQLLCCJJJCCCLLCCCLQQQLLLQQQQLQ0000QLLLZk&@WhdqmOL0qoWJ~,^""``^`..'.^_rq#hdpdkbddbkkkkkbbbbddbbbbbbbbbbbddbbbbbbkkkkkkkkkbbkkkkbkkbdbkkkkbbdbbkkkbbkhkkbkkkbdbaM%8kZCYXzccvccccccvvvvcunuvvvccvccvvuuuuuuuuuvvuuucczzzzXXXXXzzzzzzzXXXXXYUUYXzzXYYXXXXXzzXXXXXzzczXYYYYYUUJJUUJQZdhapLUJLZpkkdwZO0000QLCJUU
LLLLCCJJJJJCCLQ0QLLQQQLLLLCLLCCLLLQ0O0LLObW@&hdqZ0LOb#&Y>:;"^^^^^'..`ixqaobppdddpdkkbbbddbbbbbbbddbbbdbbdddbbkkbbkkbbbbbbbbdbbbbbbbbbkbbdddbkkbbbbkkhhkbbddbkhhkhM&&oZQCJJUYYYXXzzccvvvuuuuuuvuuvzcvuuuuvvuuuvcvvvvvvcczXXXXzcczzXYYXXXzczzzzzzzXYYYXzcczXYYXXXXYJJJJUUUUJJUUUJLOOCLZqbkaakpZOZqbbbdbkhahbwm
LLLLLLCCCCCCLLQLCJCLLCJJJUUUJCLLLLLQQLCJQp#$WhpmZOQZkMWY<;I,^^^`''.'!(OWodpdbbddddbddddpddbdbbkbddbbddbbbbbbbkkbdddbbddbbbbbdddbkkkkkkkbdddbbkbbbbbbkkbbbddddkhkba#B&d0JUUYYXYYYXzcccvvcccvvvnnnuvuuvvuuuvcvuuuuuuuvvcccccccccvvvvzzcczzczzzzXXzXXXXzccczXUUzccXJLLCUYXYYYYUUJL0LJXXCZdbdmQJUYYUJJJUUJJCQQLL
CCCCJJJJUJCCCCCCCJCCCCCJJJJJCCLLQLLQQCCJObMBWhpmmZOmb#8J~l!I:,"..`^;{zbWhpbkbbdddddbbbbddbbbbbddddkkdddbbbkbbbdddbbbbdppddbbddbbkbdbkkbbdbbbbbbdbkkbbbbbbbbbbbkkbba88oqCYYXzccczzzXXzzzzzcczcvvuunnuvvvuvczzccccvuuuuvvvvvvvvvvvvvczzXXXzzzczXYXXXzzzXYYYYYYXzzXYYYYYYUUYYYYYYYYzzzXYUUYXzzzzzzXXXXzzcccczzz
CCCCJJUUYJJJJJJJJJJJCCCCCCCCCCCLLLLQQQQQmkW$WhdwmZOZq#$O[l:^`^^`'.`lfmo#bwpdbbddbbddddddba*M*kbdddbkbbkkbbbbbbbbkkkkbbbbkkkbbbbbkbdbbbddbkkbbbbbkkkkbbbbbbbbbbbbbbh#W&ow0JYXzczccccvuuuuuvvvvvvvvcvvvvccccccczzcvvvvcccccccczzzzcccczXXzzcccczXYYYXzccccvczzXXXXzzzzXXXXXzcczXXXXXXXXXzccczccccczzzzzzzXXXXX
JJCJUUUUUCLLLLLCCCCJUUYYUUUUYUJLLQQ00QLLObM$WkpwmmmZmo$q/~,^^^`''':-za*adqpdddppddbddbbbkhM%Wahkbbbbkhkkbbkkkbbbbbbkbbbkkkbbkkkkkkkbkkkbbkbdddbbkhkbbbddbbbddbkkkbka#8#pQXzcunnnrrxxxnuuunnuunnxnnxrrrxnnxjjjrxrrrxxxxxxxxxxrrnunnnnnnnnxxxnnunnnnxxxnnnxxnuuuuuuunnnuuunnnuuvvuunnuvvvuuvcccvvvvvvvvvvuuuuu
JJJUYYYYYJCCCCCCLLLCJJUUJJUUUUCLLLLCCCCC0q*%&obqwmmmma%dn-";I^.  '~jw&oqpbao##*##MM*ooaaaoM%&#ohhhhhhhkkkhhkkbddddbbbbbbbbbdkkbbdbbkkkbddbbbbbddbkbbbbbbbbbka**ahhkk*8MbQvnxjft/\|||/fjft////\\\||||((|\||(((|||||\|||||\\\\\\tfjjjjjftt/tfjrrrjjjffjrrrjjrxxxrxxxrrrxrrrrxnxrrjjjrrrjjjjrrxxrjfffffjfffffff
CCJUYYYYUJCCCJJCCCCJJJJJJJJJJJJJCCCJJJJC0w*B&okpmOOOZk8hY},;I"'   !\Ca**&88#dOJJJXcYC0mh*#&B8#ahhoW&WWWW&&WMMMM#*ahhkhhaahhkkkbbkhkbbddbbkkbbkbbbbbbbbbbbddh*MMakbbbo88#mXvurft/\\\\||||()1)(|()))(((((|||||\\\\/\\\\\\||\//////ttffft////tjrjjjjjfffffftfjjffjjjrrxrjjjjjjfffjjrrjft/ttfftttfftttttffffffff
JJJUYYUUUCCCJUJJJJJJJJJJJUUUJJJCLLLCJCCCQwo%WhdwZOOOObMa0|Il!,`'...'I?\v0db0f1]??_~+--|Jk8B%Moao#W%$BB$$BBBBB%8W#**M&8&M#***#MMMWM*ahkh*#M*ahhhkkkkkkkbbkbbh*W&#ahaoM%%WqYzvxft/////\()\jxnf\()(((((|||||\\\|\\/\((|\//||\/t/\\||||\\//////ttttffft/ttffffjjfffjrrxrjft///////////\\|||\\\\\\\////\\\\\/////
000QLCCJUUUUJJUYYUJJJUUUUUJJJUJCCLLCJJJCQZh&*pZQ00QQQwohZ/Ili:^^^'''.  `}xJz[<?-~~~<<+|Ch8&abbaM&%88&&W&&%$$B%&M*oo#W%WoaoM8BBBBB8MoahoM&&Mo*WM#oahhaao*#*aaoW8M*o*WWodOUvnxrft///\|()\XZdmr\xJwmJx|(|\///||(((()11)|//|()))(||(((((||\\\\\||||\\\\\//ttt//tttttftttt/\\||||((|||(||()(())(|||(((((((|\/\|||
UUJJJCCJUUUUUUUYYYYXXXYYUUYYYYUJCLLCCJJL0mhWopZQO0CUJZaopr<~+I"^^^`'.. `/UJn?<]-<<~<+[jw**oa*MW&M*akkkbh*W%B%&#*aao#&BWooM8BBBBB$%W#*aoW%8Wo*&8&888888%BB%&WWMaJjtckomJcuxrffttttt//txXQmZ0JLw*BMqOLJzxt/\\||()11))(|||(){{{1)(((((((((||((()))(((((|\\\\\\\\\\|\||||||||||))(||)1)((())1)|||((()))))(((((((
UUUYXXXXXXXYYXXXXXXXXXXYUUUUYYUJLQQQ00Zwpb#%MkwOZ0JYUZaaqtI!!^.        "vmXt-<_+~~+>_\Uo&hh#WW#akbbkkbbddh*MWM#oahhoM&W##MMM**#M&8&W##M8B%&MM88888888%$$BB%B%Mpu)\X#WZUcunrftfxvXC0Zw0JUJ0ZZQYQbdZmqhk0zr/|(())1)(((()1)))))))(((()))))))))))11)(()))(((())((((((((((||||||)(||((((()(()1)(((((((())(())))))
OOZmmmwwwwwqpddbbbbkkkkkkkkkkkkao***#W&%%8B$&admOLUYJma#aLnnunxrjfjrrxxXo80x|{[_<~_~[cp88kdkkbppdkkkbddbbbbbbbkhkkkbkkhhhkbbbkkkkhhhkkhao*****oa*M&%B%W&B$$$B#wn|tJW&ZUvnrrrjffffruczx//fjjft\/ft|11rYQOLJYzcunxxjt\|(()((||||((((((((((((|||))((((((|||(()((||||||||||(((()(|((|||())()11111)((())))())1111
#MWW&&WWW#*###*o****ahbddppqqwmwwqqqqmmZZwh&&#dOCUXXJZa&%Moaaao*###MMM&%$WQnj\)[-__+1Uh88kdbbbbbbbbbbbbbbkkbbbddbbkkkbbbbbkkkkbbkkkkbbbbddbkhkbbh*W8W#hh*&B$$oOvffY#Wp0Jzvuunnnnxxrrjjfjrffrrjt/\//\|\fnvXUUYUUYzurf//\||||||||||||((())))))))(|||(((((())1)|||||||||(()))111))((())()1{{{{11)((()))))((((((
OOOO00QQQCJCCJUUUUUUYYYUUUUYYYYYYYYYYYXXYCwo8$8M*ooo###ohqOOOQQ00QLLQOda#dn(/([??_-}jq&&#bdbbbbddbbbbbbbkbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbkkkkkbkkbbbbbbbbbdpddkhhhhkkkbaWB$hCx/tUW8pQUzccvnxnunnnxrxnnuuuuxffrrfffffffft////tttt///ttft////////tttt//\\\\\\((||||((||(()))||||||((((((((||()11(()))1{1(()(((((((())1)))111
YYXXXXXXXXYYUUYYXXXXYUUUUUUUUUJJJJJUUUUUJCL0wdppppqwwZ00QQLLQ00000OOZm*8hQr||)]--_?/U#$*kbddppdbbkbbbbkbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbkkbbbbbbbkkkbkbbbbbbbbbbdbkkkbpdh&$hJj\x0%%qQCYXXXcuxxnuuunnnnnnnxrrrxxxrrxxxrrrrrjjffffjjjjjjfttt//////tffffffffjjtttt/\\\\/\\\\\///\|||\\|((((||)111)(((())))1111{{{11)))))))(((
uuunuunnxnnuvvuuuvvccczzvvccccXXzzzccvvczXzzzzzzzczcvczXXYXYYXXYYUUJLmW$qc/)){]-??)YdW&kpkkbbdbbkkbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbkkkbbbbbkkkkkbbkkkkkkkbbkkkkkka&$dXjjJd%WmLLJUYYzcccccvvuuuuuunnxxxnnunnxxnnxxxxnxxxrjjrxnnxrjjjjffffffjjfffttfjjttffftttfff//////tttttfftttttftt/\\/tt/\\/\||||((((|\\\\///tfff
xrjjjjjffjjjjjfffjjjjjrrrrnxrxxxxrrjrrrrjjrxrrrrrrjffjrxnnxjffrnnnxxcLM$Zx/(1[-+_[/m&MobdkkkkbbkkkkkbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbkkbbdbbkkkkbbbkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkbkbkkbbkWBdXrn0hWo0JJUYXzzzccccvvvvvvvvvunnnuuunxrrrxxrrrxrrrxrrxnnxrrxnuxrjjjjffjjfttffjjjfjjrjffjrxjjjjttjjffffjjrxxxxjrrrrxxrjffjfffjftttffjjfffjjjjjj
jjjjjjjfftffjfjjjjjjjjjjffft//fffjjfftttfjjjt//tfjfffjjrrjffjjrrrrxxuU*B0f\()}?-](nbB#kkkhhhkkkkkkkkbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbkhkdddbkhkkbbkkkkkbbbbbkkkkbbbkhhkbbkWBdXrxOa#hQUYzvccccvuuuuunuuuvvunnnnnnnnnnnxxxnnnxrrxxnxxrjjjrxnnnnxxxxrrrrrjfjrxxrrxxxxjjrxxrjrrffjjjjjrrrxxxrjfjxxrxxxrjjrrjxxxrjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
ffttffffffffffffjjjjjfff//tt//tfffffft////tft//ttfffffrrrjjrxxxrrnnncC#BQt(11[--[tUo$Mkhhhkbbbbkkkkkkbbkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkbbbbkkkkbbbkkkkkkbbbbkkkkbbbbbkkdba&$pcfrZo#kQJUXcvvunxnuunnxxxxnnxxxxxxxxnuuunnnnnnrrxnnnxxxxxxxxnnuunxnnnnxxrrrrrrrxxxxxxrrxrrrrnuuuunnnnnnnnuunrjrnnnxxnnxxxxxxxxxrrrjjjrrjjjjjjj
tt/tttftttffffffftttttff//////ttttttffffffffjjfffffffjrxnuuuuuuvvuuuUm&BQft|{]__[r0#B*bkhkkbddbkhhkkbkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkbbbkkkkkbbbbkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkbbbkkbbh&$pcjnq#MkLYYzvunnnnnuuvuunnuuuunnuuuunnuunnnnxrrrnuvvuuuvcvvuuvvuunuuvccvuuvvvvuuuuuuuuvvunxrxnuuunnnuvunxxnnnnnnuunxxxnnxrrrrrxxxrjjrxnnnnxxxxx
fttt//////ttfffjjtttjjjffjxxxrjjjjfjrrxxnunnnnuuuxjjrxnuunxnuvvvuvuvQb#az||)[--?1vqM%obbkhhkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkbbbbbbkkkkkkkkkkkkhhkkkkkkkbbbbbbbkkkkkkkkbbkkkkkW$bUnuZoWhCXzccvuvuuunnvvvunuvvuuuvuxrxuvunuunxrrrxnuuuuunnnnuvvuxrrrxnuuuuuuuuuvvvvvvvvvvvunxxxnnnnxxxxxxnnnnnnnuuunnxrxnnnxxnuunxxuvcvuuvuuuvvv
///\\\\//tffffjrrrrrjjjjrrjjrjjjrrrrrrrxxxxxxnnnxrjjxxxnnnnnnnuvuunvQkhqu|\|}?][(UaMMakhhhhhhhkkkkkkkkkkkkkbbbbbkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkbbbkkbbW$kUxrCbWoLXXzccvuuuuuuvvuuuuvvunnunrjjrxnnxxnxxxxnnnuxrrrxnnxrrrxxxxrrxnnxxrjjjrxrrxxnnuuuunxxnnnnnnnxxxxnnnxxxnnnnxnnxxnunxxxnnnrrnuuunnuuuuuuu
\\\/ttttt////ttffjjjftffjf//tttttfjjjjjfffjrrrftfjjrrjjrxrrxnxxrxxxv0hhZt-1)}?-]|C#W#kdkkbbkkkkkkkkkbbbkhhkkkkbbbbbkkkkkkkbbbbbbkkkkkkkkkkkkkkbbbbbbbkkkkkhW$hCnn0a8oLXXcvvunnnnnnnnxnnnnunrrnnxrrrxnnxrxrjjrjjjjjrrxxxxxrrxxxjjrxuunxxnnxrrjrrrrrrxnnnxxrxxxxnnnnnnnnuunxnunxrjrxxxnxxxrrrxnnxxxrjjrnnnnuuu
ffffffffffffftfjrrrrrxnnxrxxxrjffjxxxxnxxxnuunrfjjxrjfffjjruvxrjjxxnLkhmt-)(}]??{nmW$#kkkbbkkkkkkkbbbbbbhhhkkkkbbbbkkkkkkkkkbbbbbbkkkkkkkkkkkkkkbbbkkkkkkkh&$aQuuZaMkYvcuxnnxrrrxnnxrjjjjxnrjrjjjrjfjjjrxjttjjjjjjjrrjjfffjjrrjffrnnnnnuunxxxxxnnnnuuunxrrxxxxxnnnxxxxxxxrxxrjt/tfffjjfjjjjrrxxrjjrrxnnnnnnn
nxxrrrrxxxrjjfjxxxrxnnnxxxnxxrrrxxxxrxxnnnnnxxxxxxnnxxxrrxnuunnuunxnYwMWU|(1}[[-~]tOM8WkdkhkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkbbkkkkhkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkhkbdkMB*mzvZa#bXvcuxnnnxxxnnxrjjjjjxxrjjrrxnxjjrxxxrjjxxxxrxxxxxxrrrrrrrxxrrrrjjjrrrrxxjfffttffjffttfffffjjjjjjfffjjrrrjttffffffffjffjrrrrjffjjjrrjjjj
xxnnuuunnnnnnunxxxnnnxxxnnnnnnvvunxxnnnnnnnxxrnnnnnnxxnnnnuxxnuvuxrjxzp*qYt)(1]-_+?/Y*$&ohkkkkkkkkkkkkkkbbkkkkkbbkkhhhhkkkkkhhhkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkhhhhhkkhhkka&BoZvnOhMbYcXvxxnxrrjjjrjfftffjjfftfrxxrjffjjftttjjjftfffffjjjrrrrrrrrrjjjjjjjrrrrjjjffffffftttfft/////tt/\\\/ft/tt//ttt/t/////tttffffffjffffjjjj
``````````

### On path-likes

@TamoghnaChowdhury suggests

> taking `path` as an actual `pathlib.Path` instead of as a `str`, at least for the purposes of the type hint. Maybe even `path: pathlib.Path | str` to shut the type checker up (I'm not sure where you can get the type annotation `PathLike` from)?

You can use `os.PathLike`. However, if we were to abide by the protocol of the inner `open()` call, then a `PathLike` is incorrect, because it can also take a file-like:

```
    :param fp: A filename (string), pathlib.Path object or a file object.
       The file object must implement ``file.read``,
       ``file.seek``, and ``file.tell`` methods,
       and be opened in binary mode.
```

But I consider all of that to be a bit much for this application, and would constrain it to `PathLike` for simplicity and clarity.

### Simplified algorithm

I don't think you need to bisect. You can simply load the image in `'F'` mode (32-bit floating-point), scale to your min and max, round to the nearest index and then index into your charset. You can take the opportunity to improve Numpy vectorisation and eliminate your loops.

```py
from os import PathLike
from pathlib import Path

import PIL.Image
import numpy as np


CHARSET = (
    "@$B%8&WM#*oahkbdpqwm"
    "ZO0QLCJUYXzcvunxrjft"
    "/\|()1{}[]?-_+~<>i!l"
    "I;:,\"^`'. "
)


def resize(image: PIL.Image.Image, new_width: int = 300) -> PIL.Image.Image:
    width, height = image.size
    new_height = new_width * height / width / 2.5
    return image.resize((round(new_width), round(new_height)))


def pixel_to_ascii(pixels: np.ndarray, light_mode: bool = True) -> str:
    direction = 1 if light_mode else -1
    charset_str = CHARSET[::direction]
    charset = np.array(tuple(charset_str), dtype='U1')

    minp = pixels.min()
    maxp = pixels.max()
    scaled = (pixels - minp) / (maxp - minp) * (len(CHARSET) - 1)
    indices = np.around(scaled).astype(int)

    ascii_array = charset[indices]
    rows = ascii_array.view(f'U{pixels.shape[1]}')[:, 0]
    return '\n'.join(rows)


def convert(path: PathLike) -> str:
    greyscale_image = resize(PIL.Image.open(path).convert('F'))
    return pixel_to_ascii(np.array(greyscale_image))


def main() -> None:
    ascii_img = convert('archived/image2l.png')
    print(ascii_img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The use of ```light_mode``` is pretty clever. I didn't thought of doing that.

Comment: What do the "arrows" means? (The parts that do ```->something``` outside of a function) I've seen them a lot but I have no idea what they are

Comment: Return value type hints

Comment: I'd suggest taking `path` as an actual `pathlib.Path` instead of as an `str`, at least for the purposes of the type hint. Maybe even `path : pathlib.Path | str` to shut the type checker up (I'm not sure where you can get the type annotation `PathLike` from)?

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury See edit.